# Moodle installation - Service Unavailable error

Tags: apache, moodle

when installing moodle, when moodle is creating the database tables I get after 10 seconds or so this error:

"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

The server has cloudlinux but the limits for CPU, memory, IO, processes are temporary disabled (set to unlimited)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, my issue was because an outdated mod_lsapi which cloudlinux uses to serve PHP. After the update the  moodle installation went OK.